# Silverlight datagrid column value from another table

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight

I have a specialprice lookup window in my silverlight project which is bound to a specialprice table. I have productcode and price in that table. I want to display the product name for each code in the datagrid. The productnames corresponding to the code are in another table named products. I tried using IValueConverter. Since the Linq query is executed asynchronously, I can't return the value

```
 string ProductName = "";
   public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
   {
       string ProdCode = value.ToString();
       var GetProdNamesQuery = GV.dbContext.Load(GV.dbContext.GetProdNamesQuery(ProdCode));
       GetProdNamesQuery.Completed += new EventHandler(GetProdNamesQuery_Completed);
       return ProductName;
   }

   void GetProdNamesQuery_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
   }

   public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
   {
       throw new NotImplementedException();
   }
```

any other way I can sort this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the product name as part of the original query.

If you are using Linq to SQL (your question isn't clear on that), in your data source you'll need something like:

```
DataLoadOptions options = new DataLoadOptions();

options.LoadWith<SpecialPrice>(p => p.Product);

this.DataContext.LoadOptions = options;

var query = from specialPrice in DataContext.SpecialPrices
            select party;

return query;
```

This will return the product information through the `Product` field of your `SpecialPrice` class as long as you mark the property with the `[Include]` attribute.

Then in your grid you can simply have a column that binds to the product name like this:

```
<grid:TextColumn Key="Product.ProductName" ... />
```

Comment: Hi Chris, Thanks for the solution, I have some doubts: this.DataContext.LoadOptions was not available for me, I am using EF. The [Include] attribute has to be applied to the property in the metadatafile?

Comment: @sony - ah, don't know about the Entity Framework - it might do all that for you, but yes the `[Include]` needs to go on the property definition in the meta data file.

Comment: [Include]                                                             public string Name { get; set; } -- like this rite?

Comment: @sony - no - on the `Product` Property of `SpecialPrice`.

Comment: internal sealed class CustSpecialPriceMetadata
      {

         // Metadata classes are not meant to be instantiated.
          private CustSpecialPriceMetadata()
         {
         }         

         public string CustomerId { get; set; }
          [Include]
         public string ProductId { get; set; }
         public string Type { get; set; }
         public Nullable<decimal> Price { get; set; }
        
      }
   } ---like this ?

Comment: I recreated the DataServices class and then added the [Include] attribute and its working fine... Thanks a million Chris

Answer (score 0):

Put your code of async execution in a getter of a new property and then use

```
       Myvalue="{Binding IsAsync=true, MyViewModelProperty}"

       public string MyViewModelProperty {
            get {
                ////your converter code in synchronous pattern.
            }
       }
```

So your binding will call the getter asynchronously on it's own and display value accordingly as n when it gets available.

Make sure you **don't** call the query completed in the getter as that would make it async. The getter **has** to be synchronous.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using EF + WCF RIA you may `[Include]` that Name property and in xaml just bind it directly.